# Function only works at losing condition and not winning condition

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When players lose the game the gameFun function is called but for some reason when i switch alert(win) to gameFun and the alert(lose) in processAnswer to alert(win), it doesn't work. My aim is to ask users a question after they won or lost the game.

```
--ball collides with balloon
function ballCollision(e)
    if (e.other.name == 'balloon') then
       --ball collision codes
    end

    if(target.text == '0') then
        alert('win')
    end
end

function checkGameover()
    print( "Check game over" )
    for i = 1, cannonBalls.numChildren do
         print( i )
         if(tonumber(ballRemain.text) <= 0) then
             gameFun()
         end
    end
end

function gameFun()
    balloonText.isVisible = false
    balloonTextt.isVisible = false
    balloonTexttt.isVisible = false
    questionText.isVisible = false
    askUser = display.newText('Is the cannon hard to use?', display.contentCenterX, display.contentWidth / 4, native.systemFont, 20 ) 
    askUser:setFillColor(135, 75, 44)
    yesBtn = display.newImage("Yes.png",120,290)
    noBtn = display.newImage("No.png",190,290)
    yesBtn:addEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
    noBtn:addEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
end

function ansQuestion(event)
    if event.target==noBtn then
        answer = answer+0
    else
        answer = answer+1
    end
    print('send mail')
    sendMail()
    askUser.isVisible = false
    yesBtn.isVisible = false
    noBtn.isVisible = false
    yesBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
    noBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
    alert('lose')

end

function alert(state)
    gameListeners('rmv')

    local alert
    if(state == 'win') then
        alert = display.newImage('win.png')     
    else
        alert = display.newImage('lose.png')
    end
    askUser.isVisible = false
    yesBtn.isVisible = false
    noBtn.isVisible = false
    print("time from start: ", (system.getTimer()-gameTime))
    alert.anchorX = 0.5
    alert.anchorX = 0.5
    alert.x = display.contentCenterX
    alert.y = display.contentCenterY
    transition.from(alert, {time = 3000, xScale = 0.3, yScale = 0.3})

    local score = display.newText(score.text, 300, -30, native.systemFontBold, 20)
    score:setFillColor(135, 75, 44)
end
```

Also when sendMail function is on, it gives me this 
[image]

As far as i can tell, it keeps going back and forth between ansQuestion and alert(state). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is no "processAnswer" in your code, did you mean "ansQuestion"? Also when you put code, please look at the preview to see if the indentation is correct. It wastes a lot of time when you can't rely on indentation to determine extend of code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `alert(lose)` in `ansQuestion()`, Lua interprets `lose` as a variable, not a string. Since the variable does not exist, it is nil, so the second branch of the `if (state == 'win')` gets executed. It so happens that in the case of "lose", this is the branch you want, but it is just luck. When you do `alert(win)`, win is also a variable so it is nil, so the same branch gets executed, and that time it is the wrong branch. Use

```
alert('lose')
```

and

```
alert('win')
```

as you did in `ballCollision` listener. Note that there are several lines of duplicate code in ansQuestion and alert.

Comment: thanks i didn't notice the 'lose' thing. The duplicates are because the code doesn't work in ansQuestion so i also copy and pasted over it to alert(state)

Answer (score 0):

In your alert function you passed the string value 'lose'. That's why it's always calling losing condition.
As per my knowledge, you need to call this function.

local answer = 0

function ansQuestion(event)

```
if event.target==noBtn then

    answer = 0

else

    answer = 1

end

 sendMail()

askUser.isVisible = false
yesBtn.isVisible = false
noBtn.isVisible = false
yesBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
noBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', ansQuestion)
alert(answer)
```

end

function alert(state)

```
gameListeners('rmv')

local alert
if(state == 1) then
    alert = display.newImage('win.png')     
else
    alert = display.newImage('lose.png')
end
askUser.isVisible = false
yesBtn.isVisible = false
noBtn.isVisible = false
print("time from start: ", (system.getTimer()-gameTime))
alert.anchorX = 0.5
alert.anchorX = 0.5
alert.x = display.contentCenterX
alert.y = display.contentCenterY
transition.from(alert, {time = 3000, xScale = 0.3, yScale = 0.3})

local score = display.newText(score.text, 300, -30, native.systemFontBold, 20)
score:setFillColor(135, 75, 44)
```

end